# How to limit a Spring @Configuration class to instantiating only alternate services?

Tags: java, spring

I have a project which is expanding quickly and now has over a hundred components. For unit testing, I have a `@Configuration` class to substitute stubbed classes, such as a database service with limited functionality:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringDevTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Profile("unittest")
    public DatabaseService databaseService() {
        // this one is needed for the test
        return new TestDatabaseServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("unittest")
    public RobotControlService robotControlService() {
        // Why should I do this on every service?
        return new RobotControlServiceImpl();
    }

... etc.
```

The vast majority of components don't need test alternatives, so we want the default one that exists and is picked up at runtime. But whenever a new component is added to the system, we have to add it to all of the `@Configuration` classes, or we get the "`NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`: No qualifying bean of type..." exception. That's a lot of boilerplate code to return Impl classes, and prevents us from making implementation classes package-protected (because the configuration class needs to be able to instantiate them).

I have tried adding `@ComponentScan` to the class, but that results in `BeanDefinitionOverrideException`. If I allow bean overrides with:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

... then I get `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` because of the multiple database service implementations.

I'm sure I must be missing something. How can I have short, simple `@Configuration` class that only instantiates the test implementations I need for the test, then allows the other services to be discovered automatically without explicitly creating them?

Comment: Consider using Mockito instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking about how to stop enumerating the (hundreds of) non-mocked services.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example project? Though it is likely necessary to have *some* bean duplication, it isn't typical to have to add it to "all the `@Configuration` classes." Typically, your app configuration is done so that only what differs between profiles (dev, prod, test, etc.) can be overridden in the yml/xml configuration files. In this case, if *every* single bean has a specific test implementation, your test setup is likely not very meaningful.

Comment: Some more information... I see other `@Configuration` annotated classes in the system with only one to five `@Bean` methods (some mocked, some not). But in the case of this one, it's really an integration test that generates tens of thousands of tests using `@TestFactory` (from JUnit 5) on thousands of individual business-logic classes. Since they are integration tests created dynamically, they need most of the real services available when they run. It seems like Spring doesn't have a way to easily default to component scanned services.